# White text on yellow background in popup elements with Ambiance theme

Tags: gnome, ambiance

In Eric4, when I select the "What's This" tool and then click on something to get a pop-up explanation, the resulting text appears white on yellow (unreadable). The tool-tips are fine (white on black). If I change the theme to any other, the text is black on yellow. I've found some posts on the internet about such behaviour with Skype and LibreOffice, but it doesn't seem to me to be the program-specific problem since it appears in various apps.

How can I tune it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem, but for Xubuntu 12.04 > the texts in may applications were white, against a white background.

What I learned from my case, was that many themes are not yet fully adjusted to gtk-3.0 settings. Selecting a different theme can help here.

If you are a bit more adventurous and know how the theme files work, you can try this solution: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1966684

With the instructions found on that page, you will have to change a few lines in the gtk-widgets.css file. It worked for me.
Lines with a (-) in front need to be removed. Lines with (+) in front need to be added.